# Spring return String as JSON, Behaviour changed

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

During product upgrade from Spring 3.2 to 4.3 I stumbled about a breaking change.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{category}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateMessages(@PathVariable final String category,
        @RequestBody final Map<String, String> messages,
        @RequestHeader(value = "ForceLanguage", required = false) final Locale locale) {
    if (locale == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("A locale must be given!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    messages.remove("id");
    messageService.updateMessages(locale, category, messages);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This method simply returns OK.

With Spring 3.2 there is a header: `Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8` and the response body contains `"OK"`

With Spring 4.3 there is a header: `Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8` and the response body contains `OK`.
This is not JSON.

**Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?**
Can it be a change in Jackson?

**Update**: It is not Jacksons fault!

```
    log.debug("ObjectMapper: {}", objectMapper.getClass());
    try {
        log.debug("Test: {}", objectMapper.writeValueAsString("OK"));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error("", e);
    }
```

I used the configured ObjectMapper bean directly and wrote the conversion to the log.

```
2017-07-31 13:41:21.608 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] de.company.product.web.I18nController      : ObjectMapper: class de.company.product.json.CustomObjectMapper
2017-07-31 13:41:21.610 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] de.company.product.web.I18nController      : Test: "OK"
```

Comment: have you tried tagging the method with `produces="application/json"`?

Comment: In Chrome `JSON.parse("OK")` throws an Error, "OK" is not a valid JSON string

Comment: yes I tried produces but it does not change the behaviour. As you know, this is the default. You can see, that it is already returned as Header.

Comment: You are right JSON.parse ("OK") will lead to an error :D, Correct is JSON.parse ("\"OK\"") because this is valid JSON

Comment: Good point, I missed the escaped quotes

Comment: Your Controller class is annotated with @Controller or @RestController?

Comment: Good point and I tried that. No difference between `@Controller` and `@RestController`

Comment: I will request you adding the @ResponseBody. Docs explain it like this. This annotation can be placed on a method and indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name)

Comment: With @RepsonseBody I can not use ResponseEntity any more right? So how do I influence headers and status?

Comment: You know this or you are just guessing?

Comment: No it's not a guess, If I use @ResponseBody, it can not return a ResponseEntity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spring does not allow to specify that a String must be converted to JSON.**

**Spring also does not care about produces setting for Strings!**

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

The reason is the default configuration in [WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java). Especially the `StringHttpMessageConverter` coming before `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

Next Problem, if you register the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` by yourself you lose all default message converters.

My Solution was to copy most of the code from the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`...

```
@Configuration
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private final static void
            addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        final StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        stringConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
        messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(stringConverter);
        messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<>());
        messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(feederObjectMapper()));
        addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Gson gson= new Gson();
return new ResponseEntity<>(gson.toJson("OK"), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Check what response you get on the client now.

Comment: You are joking, right? I would have to search the whole project and change all methods to build JSON on my own, because it is not working out of the box? And then one day the issue is fixed and the JSON is wrapped into JSON twice... I don't think this is a solution.

Comment: As stated above, produces="application/json" should have worked. I understand your concern. I just added a work around and I agree with you. Can you just try using passing your text with escape characters?

Comment: Also you can wrap the String in  an object, that is one another workaround.

Comment: Gson is not know to my project. I don't have a dependency for this. The workarounds do not work for a real world project. The impact for unnecessary wrapping is to massive. All apps using the REST service would have to change all methods that return a String so fare. The risk with custom to JSON is, that if Spring behaviour once again changes, we have double escaped JSON...